# Error in referencing custom schemas in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Node.js newbie here...
I have a two schemas and I am referencing one within the other.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/*Model for user settings */

var SettingsSchema = new Schema({
shoppingDay: {type: String, default : "Friday"},
shoppingFrequency : {type: String, default : "weekly"},
reminderEmails : {type: Boolean, default : true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Settings', SettingsSchema);
```

and

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
var Settings = require('./Settings.js');
var SettingsSchema = Settings.Schema;   

/*Model for user settings */
var UserTrendSchema = new Schema({
    email : String,    
    settings  : SettingsSchema
},
{collection : 'UserTrends'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserTrend', UserTrendSchema);
```

I am running into this error

```
throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema path `'+ prefix + i +'`');
```

but if I make it an array, it works.

```
settings  : [SettingsSchema]
```

I don't want it to be an array. Just a single instance of settings. All the examples I see use their custom types as arrays.

I also tried

```
settings  : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Settings'}
```

but it just creates an entry in the DB with an object id and does not include the default values

```
 "settings": {
    "$oid": "54ccfdcb5926074c1d53d02f"
},
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: did you export settingsSchema **module.exports = SettingsSchema ;**

Comment: Yes I did. I have edited my question to show the full file

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want setting to be an `Array` you can keep settings as Object and refer it to the Settings model. while fetching you can populate the settings.

**Changes**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/*Model for user settings */

var SettingsSchema = new Schema({
shoppingDay: {type: String, default : "Friday"},
shoppingFrequency : {type: String, default : "weekly"},
reminderEmails : {type: Boolean, default : true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Settings', SettingsSchema);
```

---

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    

/*Model for user settings */
var UserTrendSchema = new Schema({
email : String,    
settings  : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Settings'} // refers to Settings Model.
},
{collection : 'UserTrends'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserTrend', UserTrendSchema);
```

Where settings will be objectId and can be populated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that earlier. It created an entry in the DB but didn't populate it with the default values.  "settings": {
        "$oid": "54ccfdcb5926074c1d53d02f"
    },

Comment: it will not populate itselt you gotta populate it while finding.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But isn't that the point of default values that when I create a new instance of Settings, it will auto populate it? When it was set up as an array, and I created a new instance (new Settings()) in one of my routes, it was being populated with the default values but this way is not picking up the default values. Am I missing something?

Comment: when you set it into an array it does not populate but it keeps the Settings as a part of the Schema.